# I'm trying to use Nifi with Flume to use Avro

Tags: apache-nifi, flume

I'm trying to send some files with Nifi. I'm able to send it with Flume, but in other step of my work I have some problems with Flume and I thought: Why do I not use Nifi instead of Flume?

I read Nifi have some problems to send data as Flume. I found something called: "ExecuteFlumeSink" and "ExecuteFlumeSource". Can you see what I'm trying?

The inside of the processor "ExecuteFlumeSink" is:

```
sink type -> avro
Agent name -> cp2
sink name -> k2
Flume Configuration -> cp2.channels =c2
                       cp2.channels.c2.type =memory
                       cp2.sinks.k2.channel =c2
                       cp2.sinks.k2.type =avro
                       cp2.sinks.k2.hostname =computer1 
                       cp2.sinks.k2.port =11111
```

I have the error: "Flume event delivery failed". Is it possible what I'm trying?

Thank You

nifi-app.log:

2018-04-12 10:53:36,402 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.p.flume.ExecuteFlumeSource ExecuteFlumeSource[id=b904159e-0162-1000-c810-813cc9cb7d6b] ExecuteFlumeSource[id=b904159e-0162-1000-c810-813cc9cb7d6b] failed to process session due to java.lang.NullPointerException: {}

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.flume.source.AvroSource.stop(AvroSource.java:302)
    at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.stop(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:51)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.flume.ExecuteFlumeSource.stopped(ExecuteFlumeSource.java:150)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.flume.ExecuteFlumeSource.onTrigger(ExecuteFlumeSource.java:171)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1122)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you share the full error message that gets thrown? This can be taken from the `nifi-app.log`

Comment: sure. Thanks. Now I only have errors in ExecuteFlumeSource, catching the document.